# Live video broadcast and server resources using RED5

Tags: video, resources, streaming, webcam, red5

how much ram do i need to run a server with red5 and broadcast live video

I am starting a project that will include live video broadcasts from all over the world and it is expected to have at least 1000 users viewing those videos in real time.

After looking around a bit i have decided to use [RED5](http://osflash.org/red5) to handle all the video streaming/recording, based on the fact that it is free and open source, but i am still open to other options (that don't include buying a FMS license).

**now i need to know how many resources will red5 be demanding to the server if lots of users start accessing the site and watching the videos that maybe 50 different people are broadcasting.**

i was thinking on renting a **VPS** with **512 MB of ram** and **800 GB of bandwidth**,

```
will that be enough?

will i need to get something with more resources?, maybe a dedicated server?
```

or maybe the best thing for me to do is rent some hosting that offers video streaming services of some kind?

Thanks, Fortes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running red5, and from my testing, you will certainly need more RAM there. To support a small userbase, I guess a gigabyte would be perfectly fine. But for thousands of users, things could scale very differently. Again I repeat, this is according to my testing, I would recommend a gigabyte, and scale from there, for your needs.

Good luck with red5, it's a great project :-)

Comment: Thankyou mr. ... i have decided to pay for a streaming hosting plan in a company called influxis, because i needed to be 100% shure my proyect is going to be working all the time... and hosting it in my own server would be verry dificult

Comment: Maybe it's the easier thing to do, and you can focus on other parts of the project instead of the server becoming another concern for you